# When I've marked a message as read in Gnus, how push that change to the server?

Tags: email, emacs, gmail, gnus

I've hooked up Gnus to my Gmail account and I'm able to send mail just fine (using `gnutls`).
However, when I mark messages as read, I cannot see my changes reflected in Gmail's web interface.
How can I push the changes I make?

Answer (score 1):

After some playing, I've found my answer.
The changes will be pushed when you exit your inbox with `q`.
If you want to see your changes immediately, you can use `M-g` (`gnus-summary-rescan-group`).